# UWP Build Issue with Resource size (.PRI file issue)

Tags: c#, uwp, azure-devops, msbuild

In my UWP project, heavily using string resources more than 20 languages and each have *50k+* key values. Also it has lot of screens and controls.

Until certain limit, not getting any build issue. But once I added 3k more keys getting unspecified build error with MSBuild. Strangely if I reduce some keys build again works.

Build Command

`MSBuild.exe MyProject.sln /p:AppxBundlePlatforms="x64" /p:AppxPackageDir="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\MyProject\AppxPackages\\" /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=SideloadOnly /p:UseDotNetNativeToolchain=false /p:Use64BitCompiler=true`

Error

```
error PRI175 : 0x80004004 - Processing Resources failed with error : Operation aborted [D:\VSTS Agent\vsts-agent-win-x86-2.155.1\_work\24\s\MyProject.csproj]
  GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE : error PRI222: 0xdef0000f - Unspecified error occurred. [D:\VSTS Agent\vsts-agent-win-x86-2.155.1\_work\24\s\MyProject.csproj]
    1654 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)
```

After sometime identified the issue with PRI file. As per [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/pri-apis-custom-build-systems) PRI file size lime is **64kb**. But it worked well for me till **18mb** (Yes! my resources.pri file size is **18.6mb** and still build and working).

As said earlier, if I add some more keys the resources.pri file becomes **21mb** and always getting failed (Release build with disabled .Net Native Toolchain)

Luckily it build successfully with .Net Native Toolchain **enabled**.

Any suggestion to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, you said that you can build successfully when you enable .Net Native Toolchain. Do you have to disable it? What is the reason for this?

Comment: There is a expectation to take build in both ways (with and without .Net native tool chain) due to other dependencies. But in production we only use .Net native enabled build. I tired to dump the pri file with makepri.exe. There I can see around 1 million lines of code in the generated XML file. It has all the image mapping and language values. If we add more more strings in future, not sure the .Net native build too break.

Comment: Hello, you can continue to use .Net Native Toolchain to build your application, I will ask the relevant engineers about this matter, if something news, I will post here.

Answer (score 0):

> As per MS Documentation PRI file size lime is 64kb.

Thanks very much for reporting this issue, I have gotten the confirmation that the 64KB limitation in the documentation is incorrect, it is going to be updated.

> As said earlier, if I add some more keys the resources.pri file
>   becomes 21mb and always getting failed (Release build with disabled
>   .Net Native Toolchain)
>
> Luckily it build successfully with .Net Native Toolchain enabled.

For the size about 21mb, it seems like that you may be hitting an upper limitation on the amount of items allowed within the PRI file.

> If we add more more strings in future, not sure the .Net native build too

Since we do review this periodically and allow for extra capacity for the PRI file, so if you still want to increase the PRI file into a more large file than 21mb, could you please try to use latest insider preview builds(20H1) to see if it helps alleviate what you are seeing?

Thanks.